# scan files from dir and scan files from dir inside dir with a smart command

Tags: php

I know the question is not understandable but let me explain:

**FolderOfImages**
this is the folder which contains:

```
1- 545.jpg
2- 546.jpg
3- FOLDER
```

**the 3- FOLDER** contains:

```
1- 785.jpg
2- 786.jpg
3- FOLDER
.
.
.
etc
```

How to scan something like this and bring the photos to the page?

Comment: Yes, with [scandir](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) and [is_dir](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php).

Comment: I'm sure a quick search on Google would have been much easier than posting the question here

Comment: Please write the code for me. really I tried the scandir and tried the glob nothing worked with me

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to use the `RecursiveIteratorIterator` provided by PHP.

```
    $dir = '/full_path_to_your_folder';
    $images = getFiles($dir, '.jpg');
    print_r($images);

    function getFiles($dir, $match) {
        $return = array();
        $iti = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir));
        foreach($iti as $file){
             if ($file->isDir()) {
                continue;
             }
             if(strpos($file , $match) !== false){
                $return[] = $file->getPathname();
             }
        }
        return $return;
    }
```

Comment: Not the downvoter but I'm pretty sure it is because you are answering a totally off-topic question as OP is asking for code

Comment: Thank you user1309690 it's working! but user1309690 I want to print Images not an array, When I'm trying to replace  print_r($images); with  echo '<img src="'.$images.'">'; it's telling me array to string conversion

Comment: @DenizBeaver Now that you have the array. You could just loop through and display on HTML Pages as you like.